# Skip rows in time range specified in table

Tags: mysql, time, innodb, between

I have a jobs table with a 'sleep phase' and I do not want to return rows that are in the range between `sleep_start` and `sleep_end`.

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sleep_start` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `sleep_end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Every job has a timeframe where it should not be called which is specified in a time format `00:00:00`

Then I'd want to run a query like

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE TIME(NOW()) NOT BETWEEN sleep_start AND sleep_end
```

And only get jobs that are not sleeping.

Now this seems to be working when `sleep_start` and `sleep_end` are on the same day and the time span does not exceed `00:00:00`. When this happens, those rows get always returned.

How can I change the query to make it work in all scenarios?

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE NOT TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN sleep_start AND sleep_end```

Comment: Spanning midnight makes for messy code; can't do it in a simple expression.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to change the query and stick with the `start` time, but change `sleep_end` to `sleep_duration` int which holds sleep time in hours, then construct a date from the time and today, same with + interval X hours

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the problem, your Time columns to represent the time of day, and that if `sleep_start < sleep_end` then we should assume `sleep_end` is on the following day.

You just need to test both of those cases.

```
SELECT * FROM jobs   
WHERE TIME(NOW()) NOT BETWEEN sleep_start AND sleep_end
AND NOT (sleep_start > sleep_end AND 
    (TIME(NOW()) >= sleep_start OR TIME(NOW()) <= sleep_end));
```

The first check (the `BETWEEN` clause) is the case where `sleep_start <= sleep_end`. But it doesn't have to check for that explicitly because `NOW()` will never be between them unless it is true.

The second half does include the check for `sleep_start > sleep_end`, and if that's the case, it checks for `NOW()` being after the later time or before the earlier time.

Comment: Let's say start is 23:00 and end is 02:00 the second half of the query would then be 02:00-23:00 which would not be intended

Comment: You are right. Serves me right for trying to do this in my head! I will rewrite the second query condition.